# Postgres C extended data type definition

Tags: c++, c, postgresql, plpgsql, postgresql-11

When dealing with the following problems, Postgres is a bit tricky to deal with more complex structures. I want to set up a two-dimensional array of structure, but I don't know how to make Postgres C support me to do so? Do anyone have any ideas?

```
Table
    id     contents(text)              num(double)
    1       I love you.            {1,3,4,5,6,7,8,10}
    2       why do it?             {3,4,2,11,12,33,44,15}
    3       stopping.              {22,33,11,15,14,22,11,55}
    4       try it again.          {15,12,11,22,55,21,31,11}
```

Sort the rows of each position of the array to get the fo.lowing structure. The result of the first row below is the first position of the num field column array, and so on.the count 4 refers to returning the first n sorted.

```
select my_func(contents, num, 4) from table;
```

expected result:

```
                           result
{('stopping.', 22), ('try it again.', 15), ('why do it?', 3), ('I love you.', 1)}
{('stopping.', 33), ('try it again.', 12), ('why do it?', 4), ('I love you.', 3)}
{('stopping.', 11), ('try it again.', 11), ('I love you.', 4), ('why do it?', 2)}
......
......
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need C extended data type, but the following will give you what you want and can be implemented as plpgsql function.

```
WITH t1 AS (
  SELECT id, contents, unnest (num) AS n FROM table
),
t2 AS (
  SELECT id, contents, n,
         row_number () OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) AS o
         FROM t1 ORDER BY o ASC, n DESC, id ASC
),
t3 AS (
  SELECT array_agg (ROW (contents, n)) AS a, o
         FROM t2 GROUP BY o ORDER BY o
)
SELECT array_agg (a ORDER BY o) FROM t3;
```

UPDATE: Problem of the above may be undefined order of 'unnest'.
The following gives consistent relation between index and num, but need to write the size of num array explicitly.

```
WITH RECURSIVE t1 (i, id, contents, num) AS (
  SELECT 1, id, contents, num[1] FROM table
  UNION ALL
  SELECT t1.i + 1, table.id, table.contents, table.num[t1.i + 1]
         FROM t1, table
         WHERE t1.id = table.id AND t1.i < 8 -- put here size of array
),
t2 (i, d) AS (
  SELECT i, array_agg (ROW (contents, num) ORDER BY num DESC)
         FROM t1 GROUP BY i
)
SELECT array_agg (d ORDER BY i) FROM t2;
```

Comment: thank for your replay, but it's wrong. the o indicates the position of the array, the result is incorrect. The position of the array element is inconsistent with o.

Comment: Sorry, 'o' and 'ORDER BY o' of t3 were missing and there are a lot of syntax error. Now rectified and confirmed the result.

Comment: Thank you, but the main problem is that the array position'o' obtained by ‘row_number () OVER’ is inconsistent with the original array element position when the amount of data is large.

Comment: Can you try my UPDATE?